# Handlebars - Get info from populated array and display result

Tags: javascript, express, express-handlebars

I'm using Handlebars to display an array on a webpage. The array should be populated with data, then I want to get the most common words from it and display the result on the webpage.

```
// Display the array on index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'my webpage', data: result});
});
```

The empty array:

```
var theArray = [];
```

Push content to the array `theArray`:

```
function getData(err, data, response) {
    var content = data.statuses;
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        theArray.push( content[i].text );
    }
}
```

Get the most common words from `theArray`:

```
if (theArray === undefined || theArray.length == 0) {
    console.log('array is empty');
}
distribution = {},
max = 0,
result = [];

theTweets.forEach(function (a) {
    distribution[a] = (distribution[a] || 0) + 1;
    if (distribution[a] > max) {
        max = distribution[a];
        result = [a];
        return;
    }
    if (distribution[a] === max) {
        result.push(a);
    }
});

result.push(result);
```

When I set `data: theArray` and push content to it, everything works fine and the content of the array is displayed. But when I change to `data: result` to display the most common words, I only get "array is empty".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are pushing the result array onto itself.. Not sure if this is what you intended. `result.push(result);`

Comment: But if I call the new array `resultArray`, I get the same result.

Comment: I see. The code snippets you have shared are supposed to work together, right? Can you please show how the data from the code snippets you have shared is available when you do `res.render('index', {title: 'my webpage', data: result});
});`

Comment: You mean like this `{{ data }}` (in handlebars template)?

Comment: What I meant was, you are defining an express route (topmost snippet in question) which does this `res.render('index', {title: 'my webpage', data: result}); });`. My question is how did `result` become available in that function?